# updated database from backend, issues when searching that field - Geocoding issue with Postal Code update

Tags: database, upgrade

So I was playing with the contact mapping option for a search profile. I noticed that mapping did not work when the postal code was entered with a space in it.
Example: "E1C E1C" rather than "E1CE1C"
When I tried to view the map I would get:
*Error This address does not contain latitude/longitude information and cannot be mapped.*

So I decided to run an update on the database: UPDATE `civicrm_address` SET `postal_code` = REPLACE(`postal_code`, ' ', '').

Which was successfull.. But still when trying to view map that error appears for the contacts that once had the space in their postal code.

If I go into the contact edit, edit the address field, change nothing, and just hit save, the issue is resolved. But I don't want to have to do that for every contact. Surely there most be a way to force it to update?

I hope I was clear with my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I've also run the Clean-up Temporary Data and Files (cleanup) Job,  but still the same issue.

Would I be correct to assume it may have something to do with updating the Geocode?

Civicrm: 4.6.10
Joomla: 3.4.5

Thanks!

I've been able to correct this issue by running the Geocode and Parse Addresses Job.

Thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to correct this issue by running the Geocode and Parse Addresses Job.

Thansk!

Answer (score 1):

After running the update command on database, you need to clear the civicrm cache (also make empty the civicrm_cache table) and delete the civicrm temporary file.

Comment: I've run the Clean-up Temporary Data and Files (cleanup) Job, which I believe should do what you suggested, but still the same issue.

Would I be correct to assume it may have something to do with updating the Geocode?